# Excel Formula & Conditional Formatting: How to match current cell in another table based on criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I have an excel tool that I use to make meal plans for clients. I select the client, choose pre-set meals from a list and compile them into a plan, and assign them to the individual.

I want to create a function/conditional formatting that highlights particular ingredients in any given meal plan, if the individual 'can't/won't eat' them. This is based off their individual preferences.

---

**Sheet 1:**
Contains a table of client names, with an associated ID. There is a drop down box that allows the user to select who they are creating the plan for.

[image: ID Selector]

**Sheet 2:**
Contains a table of ingredients, with the furthest right column containing client IDs, as text, in  the case a given ingredient is disliked by a client/s.

[image: Ingredient Table]

**Sheet 3:**
Is where the meals (and ingredients) are listed, and then compiled into a plan. Here is where I would like the conditional formatting to be applied, highlighting ingredients if they are disliked by the client.

[image: Meal Plan]

*Note: the sheets aren't actually in this order*

---

I was messing around with this formula in a cell;

```
=IF(IFERROR(IF(FIND(ID,INDEX(IngredientTable,(MATCH(IngredientInMealPlan,Sheet2!A:A,0)),9))>0,"Dislike","Error"),"Error")="Dislike",IngredientInMealPlan,"")
```

Where;

**IngredientTable** = The table of ingredients, their values, and IDs/dislikes on Sheet 2

**IngredientInMealPlan** = Would be the the ingredient in question when the meals are compiled on Sheet 3

**Sheet2!A:A** = Column A, for looking up Ingredient names

---

I realise that the formula is a bit clunky, I wasn't really sure how to tighten it up. It did start to look like I might be heading in the right direction with it, but there are several issues;

- I'm not sure how to work around **IngredientInMealPlan** relating to a specific cell, I don't think the formula will work if it's a range
- I'm not sure how to work this into conditional formatting, and apply it to the range D:D on Sheet 3 where the meal plans are compiled.

---

I'm open to ideas on how to implement this. While I realise it would make it easier, I don't really want to add an additional column to the Ingredient Table on Sheet 3. I'm useless with VBA.

Comment: Where is the client referred to in your last screenshot?

Comment: I suspect you might do better to rearrange your data just a bit. Instead of a list of Client IDs at the end of each ingredient line, assign an ID for each ingredient (basically a Unique Key). Then create another table that ties client IDs to Ingredient IDs. That should make it easier to create your formulas (might be nested `VLOOKUPs` or `SUMIFS`).

Comment: @SJR The client IDs aren't referenced on that sheet. 

The layout of the sheets in the workbook is as follows;
Ingredients (Sheet 2), Pre-set meals, Meal builder (Sheet 1), List (Sheet 3/last screenshot), PDF Maker.

There are multiple macros set up to transfer the meals/ingredients across the workbook

Comment: @PeterT Thanks for the suggestion. It would be great to be able to create a work around without having to add another table to the workbook. I'm trying to keep it as stripped back as possible. But, it may well need a table like the one you have described.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had some help, this formula works and solves my problem :)

---

```
=IFERROR(FIND('Sheet1'!$G$1,(INDEX(Ingredients!I:I,MATCH(D2,Ingredients!A:A,0)))),0)>=1
```

Where;

D2 - is the first Ingredient on 'Sheet 3'. As the conditional formatting is applied to column D, this reference changes down the column (e.g. D3, D4 ... Etc.)

Ingredients!A:A - is the column for the actual ingredient name

Ingredients!I:I - is the column for Dislikes

'Sheet1'!$G$1 - is the client ID, that has been selected

---

As the formula finds the client ID in the dislike column, the formatting is applied, alerting the user to the specific ingredient that particular client dislikes.